# remove folders from encfs control

Tags: 13.10, encfs

I have encrypted a few folders with encfs. I no longer want to do so; I want these folders unencrypted as before. How do I **remove** the folders from encfs control?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

First, I need to explain how encfs works. It basically uses 2 folders:

- a *rootdir* folder where the encrypted data is stored (for example ~/encfs/.encrypted). It is a fully normal folder, just the data can't be read directly.
- a *mountPoint* folder where the decrypted data is visible. This is the one you use (for example ~/encfs/clear). It is not a typical folder, more similar to a thumb drive.

Every modification that you make in the *mountPoint* is encrypted by encfs in the *rootdir*.

If you want to remove the data from encfs' control, you just need to move the files out of the *mountPoint* to another folder. Encfs will just consider that you have removed the data and will delete the corresponding files from the *rootdir*.

Then you probably want to get rid of the *rootdir* and *mountPoint* folders. The first step is to unmount the *mountPoint*:

```
fusermount -u ~/encfs/clear
```

After that, only the *rootdir* will remain. You can then simply remove the emptied (good idea to check first if it's really empty) folder ~/encfs/.encrypted.