# How do I delete an encrypted folder created with encfs?

Tags: encryption, encfs

I ran into bugs and complications when trying to use full disk encryption and encrypting my home folder and I am less concerned about physical security and more so about online security.

Therefore, I would like to use encfs to encrypt a folder containing my sensitive materials. Before I do so, I tested using encfs using the example outlined on the [encfs official documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption).

To practice, I created both example folders mentioned in the link above, ~/visible and ~/.encrypted. If I needed to, how do I delete the ~/.encrypted folder? This question is almost answered on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405194/remove-folders-from-encfs-control). However, it is not clear what this statement means: "After that, only the rootdir will remain. You can then *simply remove the emptied (good idea to check first if it's really empty) folder* ~/encfs/.encrypted."

In sum, how do I remove the rootdir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you make sure there's no files in ~/visible, unmount it and simply the delete the ~/.encrypted folder with

```
rm -rf ~/.encrypted
```

Or delete it with a file manager